# PHP File for WP Blog Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, html

what is the php file of the Blog page, which shows the latest posts? I can't seem to find it and I wanted to add some html, like a header title before it shows the post's name.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a file called `archive.php` will be for blog page and for blog detail page there is `single.php` file (Note : please let me know which theme you are using so i can assist you more).

Comment: Hi, it's the Lithestore one. Thank you for the reply, I'll check it out.